# How can I make this more efficient? — objects to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to massage my post data into an archive.

The post object is in the form:

```
var post = {
    title: '',
    date: '',
    published: true,
    categories: [],
    tags: [],
    slug: '',
    content: ''
}
```

And I want to massage it into an array of objects:

```
archives = [
    {
        year: 2015,
        posts: [ { title: 'Fancy Title', slug: 'fancy-title', date: date }, {..etc..}, {..etc..} ]
    }
    {
        year: 2014, 
        posts: [ {...yeah...}, {...ok...}, {... I got it...} ]
    }
];
```

I have a working function that does that:

```
function archivePosts(posts) {
    var archives = [],
        archiveObj = {};

    for (var post of posts) {
        let file = post.create(),
            year = file.date.getFullYear(),
            post2Archive = { title: file.title, slug: file.slug, date: file.date };

        file.storeAttributes(post);

        if (!archiveObj[year]) {
            archiveObj[year] = [ post2Archive ];
        } else {
            archiveObj[year].push(post2Archive);
        }
    }


    for (var key in archiveObj) archives.push({ year: key, posts: archiveObj[key] });

        archives.site = site;
}
```

But it seems inefficient to look through the posts, creating the intermediary archiveObj, and then looping through that to get it into its final form.

So my question to you lovely stackers is how can I lose that middle step of using archiveObj?

How do I test to see if there is an archives.year = year and then push the posts to the correct year's posts array (if that's the way we would solve the problem)?

Thanks as ever...

Comment: *Seems* inefficient or **is** inefficient? Sounds like premature optimisation.

Comment: sounds like a job for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A fair point well made Emissary. Asking questions about how things could be made better is how I learn.

Comment: Thanks for the link Jaromanda